# pm2 deploy and gitlab private repository

Tags: node.js, ssh, gitlab, pm2

I want to deploy my app on my remote server using `pm2 deploy`.

Here is the content of my `ecosystem.config.js` file :

```
module.exports = {
  apps: [
    {
      name: `cms`,
      script: 'cms.js',
      env: {
        COMMON_VARIABLE: 'true'
      },
      env_development: {
        NODE_ENV: 'development',
      },
    }
  ],
  deploy: {
    development: {
      user: 'username',
      host: 'xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx',
      ref: 'origin/development',
      repo: 'git@gitlab.com:MyGitlabOrg/myproject.git',
      path: '/home/username/sites/development/cms',
      'post-deploy':
        '\
        mkdir -p logs && \
        npm install && \
        npm run install:development && npm run make:development && \
        NODE_ENV=development pm2 reload ecosystem.config.js --env development',
      ssh_options: ['StrictHostKeyChecking=no', 'PasswordAuthentication=no'],
      env: {
        NODE_ENV: 'development'
      }
    }
  }
};
```

And below is the command that I use in my term (on my local machine) :

```
$ pm2 deploy ecosystem.config.js development setup
--> Deploying to development environment
--> on host xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx
  â hook pre-setup
  â running setup
  â cloning git@gitlab.com:MyGitlabOrg/myproject.git
  â full fetch
Clonage dans '/home/username/sites/development/cms'...
GitLab: The project you were looking for could not be found.
fatal: Could not read from remote repository.

Please make sure you have the correct access rights
and the repository exists.

  failed to clone

Deploy failed
```

As you can see I got this strange error `GitLab: The project you were looking for could not be found.` ...

I've checked all ssh keys, I'm able to ssh to my remote server from my local machine and I'am also able to clone the repo from my remote server.

Do you have an idea how to fix this issue ?

Thank you!

Answer (score 6):

SSH into your server and run

```
ssh-keygen -t rsa -b 4096 -C "your_email@example.com"
```

This will generate the private and public keys.
Now copy the content of the public key to paste it on GitLab.

```
cat /home/ubuntu/.ssh/id_rsa.pub
```

Next, check the SSH access to the repository

```
ssh -T git@gitlab.com
```

You should see an welcome message from GitLab.

Now you are ready to deploy from PM2.

Comment: Works the same for GitHub.

Answer (score 0):

setup your ssh for the user not root,based on your example above so you must setup ssh for username...so it will be in /home/username/.ssh/id_rsa*

Answer (score 0):

Also, ensure git fetch/ git pull works with no error on the remote server. If you see an error related to the offending ip, remove that from known hosts and then retry. Worked for me.